# Taking over a session from LoadRunner

Tags: session, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a hunch that it may not be possible but what does it take for me to ask? Hey, ["the fool didn't know it was impossible, so he did it."](https://www.quora.com/The-fool-didnt-know-it-was-impossible-so-he-did-it-Can-you-ostend-with-as-many-plausible-explanations-as-possible-this-statement-be-they-rational-or-irrational)

This question is env/tool/version agnostic. I target any industry standard tools for performance testing like HP LR, Apache JMeter, SilkPerformer etc.

The scenario:

1. A Web(HTML/HTTP) script is being executed in LR Vugen.
2. As the script execution progresses, the vuser follows the scripted steps/journey. Each [action function](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#web/webc/lrFr_webCat_Action_Funcs.htm) calls the SUT hosts/services for responses while maintaining local sessions, managing cookies and remembering headers, emulating browser caches so on.

Now, we can pause the execution any time in the tool and that will stop the vuser action. Question is, can we resume the session somewhere else or in the tool to **manually interact** with the web page or response while maintaining the same session?

This will help users reproduce a case with plenty of steps which can be executed by the tool and the user can take over at a certain point to carry with a different path.

Comment: Do you mean taking the current session and do something else instead of the following script?

Comment: Security tools and context related to session and state are designed to prevent this type of session hijacking

Comment: It very much depends on the application you are testing: authentication it uses, what it stores on client side (it will be hard to replicate all the JS objects that should exist for example) and so on. But I would do it differently: use selenium to automate the scenario up to manual point, and then take over. Selenium will run in the browser, so taking over is not a big stretch, while still allow you to achieve your goal to "help users reproduce a case with plenty of steps which can be executed by the tool and the user can take over at a certain point to carry with a different path"

Comment: You are right @Levi, that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish interaction with the session is using Looadrunner's **TrucClient protocol**.
This protocol actually uses a **real browser** (Firefox or IE emulator) for every VUser being executed. With some runtime setting options, The browser can be visible while replaying the load scenario.

Of course, TruClient protocol is only used for testing web sites.

Hope this helps.

Comment: TruClient uses an embedded browser for replay, not one that you could take over and operate manually.  However, if you use a GUI Virtual User, A Citrix Virtual User or a Remote Desktop Virtual User, driving an actual browser, then you would be able to halt execution at any point and take over the browser session.

Comment: @JamesPulley That's simply not true. You can defenitly take over a TruClient session.

Comment: Start one on a load generator from the controller, then stop it in the controller and take it over manually

Comment: While TruClient offers this control, I'd still curious to stick to my question on hijacking something over HTTP and continuing in a browser or the embedded browser if any.